# autotools: Enable compiler warnings

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, autotools

for an autotools-based C project, I'd like to get some more warnings from the compiler (e.g. at least -Wall in CFLAGS). What is the prefered way to enable compiler flags without breaking anything? Is there a m4 macro that tests if a given compiler flag is understood by the compiler?
With such a macro I could do

```
TEST_AND_USE(-Wall -Wextra <other flags>)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Widely used is the [attributes.m4](https://sourceforge.net/p/xine/xine-lib/ci/default/tree/m4/attributes.m4) CC_CHECK_CFLAG_APPEND macro from the xine project. Although, you often find variants (since it's quite simple) written directly in configure.ac

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 10):

You can just use `AC_TRY_COMPILE`:

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING(whether compiler understands -Wall)
old_CFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -Wall"
AC_TRY_COMPILE([],[],
  AC_MSG_RESULT(yes),
  AC_MSG_RESULT(no)
  CFLAGS="$old_CFLAGS")
```

---

2015 addition: `AC_TRY_COMPILE` is now deprecated, instead you should use `AC_COMPILE_IFELSE`:

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING(whether compiler understands -Wall)
old_CFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -Wall"
AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([],[])],
  AC_MSG_RESULT(yes),
  AC_MSG_RESULT(no)
  CFLAGS="$old_CFLAGS")
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't bother changing the `configure.ac` at all. Just call `./configure` with the `CFLAGS` you care about:

```
./configure CFLAGS='-Wall -Wextra -O2 -g'
```

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin Though this also addresses the need of some people, OP specifically wants automatic checks, not by human trial-and-error methods.

Comment: @AbelCheung adding cflags in configure.ac is almost always a bad idea. OP stated he wanted to add warning flags to the compiler invocation. Note that this is only useful to OP himself, not to everyone else compiling the program. hence, passing the flags to the ./configure call is entirely justified.

Answer (score 2):

I do this:

```
# debug compilation
AC_ARG_ENABLE(debug,
    AC_HELP_STRING(--enable-debug, [Debug compilation (Default = no)]),
    enable_debug=$enableval, enable_debug=no)

if test "$enable_debug" = "yes" ; then
    CFLAGS="$CFLAGS  -g -O0 -Wall -Wno-uninitialized"
    CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -g -O0 -Wall -Wno-uninitialized"
fi
```

it is a low-tech solution, but you do not have to accommodate all compilers

Comment: If you don't want to accomodate all compilers, why are you using Autotools? :)

Comment: @math I meant with respect to particular flags

Comment: why would you do production compiles with Wall turned off? I would always add -Werror too, enforces hygiene

Comment: @pm1 because some warnings I cannot suppress

Comment: @pm100: `-Werror` is a bad idea, particularly with `-Wall`, because it can cause compilation failures on test compiles which really should pass. Better, IMHO, to compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and have some discipline.